# Increase Performance of 4x4 LED Matrix (Multiplexing with pi4j)

Tags: display, led, pi4j, wiringpi

I have coded a Display-Class to drive a X by Y LED-Multiplexing-Matrix with pi4j. However, I when driving a 4-by-4-Matrix I cannot get the framerate beyond roughly 30 fps, which still produces a noticeable flicker.

When running the benchmark [included in the Git-Repository](https://github.com/Christian1984/RaspberryPiGpio/tree/master/RaspberryPiGpio/RaspberryPiTest/src/ledMultiplexing) (please see results below), I notice that the framerate INCREASES when I have less GPIO-Pins to switch. Thus, I assume that there should be a more efficient way to switch those pins on and off. Also, I am pretty sure that more LEDs will DECREASE performace even more. In my final project I want to drive a 10 x 20 LED-Matrix, thus the performance is not acceptable!

I assume that the following code-segment needs improvement:

```
public void draw() {        
    while (isAlive) {            
        for (int x = 0; x < bitmap.length; x++) {
            //pull colPin to GND
            colOutPins[x].low();
            if (verbose) System.out.println(colOutPins[x].getName() + " turned on! Pin: " + colOutPins[x].getPin() + ", State: " + colOutPins[x].getState());

            LinkedList<GpioPinDigitalOutput> switchPinsList = new LinkedList<GpioPinDigitalOutput>();
            for (int y = 0; y < bitmap[0].length; y++) {
                if (bitmap[y][x]) {
                    //set rowPin high
                    //rowOutPins[y].high();
                    //if (verbose) System.out.println(rowOutPins[y].getName() + " turned on! Pin: " + rowOutPins[y].getPin() + ", State: " + rowOutPins[y].getState());

                    //add pins to list
                    switchPinsList.add(rowOutPins[y]);
                }
            }

            //create array of pins to switch
            GpioPinDigitalOutput[] switchPinsArray = switchPinsList.toArray(new GpioPinDigitalOutput[switchPinsList.size()]);

            //switch pins on
            if (switchPinsArray.length > 0) {
                gpio.setState(PinState.HIGH, switchPinsArray);

                //wait
                try {
                    if (verbose) System.out.println("Sleeping for " + scanDelay + " ms...");
                    Thread.sleep(scanDelay);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    //e.printStackTrace();
                }

                //switch pins off
                gpio.setState(PinState.LOW, switchPinsArray);
            }

            //push rowPin to HIGH
            colOutPins[x].high();

            if (verbose) System.out.println("=== RESET FOR NEXT SCAN ===");
        }

        synchronized (this) {
            framesCount++;
            lastFrameTimeStamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas how to code my class `LedMatrixDisplayPi4j` more efficient in order to increase performance? My next step will be to go for WiringPi without the pi4j layers in between, but I'd rather see a better performance with pi4j on top!

[==> Source Code On GitHub](https://github.com/Christian1984/RaspberryPiGpio/tree/master/RaspberryPiGpio/RaspberryPiTest/src/ledMultiplexing)

```
Starting Benchmark... Stand by!
All on, 1 fps: 
Target Framerate: 1.0fps 
Actual Framerate: 0.9528851244044468 fps
Total Frames: 9 frames 
Total Time: 9445 ms

==================
Bitmap, 1 fps: 
Target Framerate: 1.0fps 
Actual Framerate: 1.023436700440078 fps
Total Frames: 10 frames 
Total Time: 9771 ms

==================
Bitmap, 10 fps: 
Target Framerate: 10.0fps 
Actual Framerate: 7.21659817580435 fps
Total Frames: 72 frames 
Total Time: 9977 ms

==================
Bitmap, 30 fps: 
Target Framerate: 30.0fps 
Actual Framerate: 15.543521861211392 fps
Total Frames: 155 frames 
Total Time: 9972 ms

==================
Bitmap, 30 fps: 
Target Framerate: 60.0fps 
Actual Framerate: 22.61583108175723 fps
Total Frames: 226 frames 
Total Time: 9993 ms

==================
Bitmap, 120 fps: 
Target Framerate: 120.0fps 
Actual Framerate: 27.56892230576441 fps
Total Frames: 275 frames 
Total Time: 9975 ms

==================
All on, 120 fps: 
Target Framerate: 120.0fps 
Actual Framerate: 24.99498092752459 fps
Total Frames: 249 frames 
Total Time: 9962 ms

==================
All Off, 120 fps: 
Target Framerate: 120.0fps 
Actual Framerate: 36.15061085519727 fps
Total Frames: 361 frames 
Total Time: 9986 ms

==================
DONE!!!
```

[==> Source Code On GitHub](https://github.com/Christian1984/RaspberryPiGpio/tree/master/RaspberryPiGpio/RaspberryPiTest/src/ledMultiplexing)